# undefined method `avatar' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fc328248ef0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to display the data for a user searched by their first or last name. I'm able to display all data returned for a user (e.g. if user is searched by first name, I can pull all other fields/data associated with the searched user, such as city, state/province, etc).

The only field that seems to be giving me an error is the avatar (profile photo) field associated with each user.  `<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>`

Note: I am able to display this field from other user pages (e.g. show.html.erb).

The error I get upon hitting the search results page is:

> NoMethodError in Users#index - undefined method `avatar' for #
>   User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fc328248ef0

**_user.html.erb**

```
<div class="card">

    <div class="columns">

        <div class="col">

  <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>


        </div>

          <div class="col">

             <div class="name">
            <%= user.firstname %> <%= user.lastname%>

    </div>
        <br>
           <b><%= user.city%>, <%= user.stateprov%></b>

</div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% if @user.present? %>
  <%= render @user %>
<% else %>
  <p>There are no posts containing the term(s) <%= params[:search] %>.</p>
<% end %>
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.search(search)
    where("firstname LIKE ? OR lastname LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
end


has_secure_password

  validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, if: -> { new_record? || changes["password"] }

has_attached_file :avatar,


 :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:basename_:style.:extension",
 :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:basename_:style.:extension",


 :styles => {
  :thumb    => ['175x175#',  :jpg, :quality => 100],
 :preview  => ['480x480#',  :jpg, :quality => 70],
  :large    => ['600>',      :jpg, :quality => 70],
  :retina   => ['1200>',     :jpg, :quality => 30]
},
:convert_options => {
  :thumb    => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip',
 :preview  => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip',
  :large    => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip',
  :retina   => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip -sharpen 0x0.5'
}

validates_attachment :avatar,
    :presence => true,
    :size => { :in => 0..10.megabytes },
    :content_type => { :content_type => /^image\/(jpeg|png|gif|tiff)$/ }


end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    flash[:success] = "You signed up successfully"
    flash[:color] = "valid"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
    flash[:color] = "invalid"
    render "new"
  end
end


def index
  @user = User.all
  if params[:search]
    @user = User.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
  else
    @user = User.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end
end



def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

if @user.update_attributes(user_params)

redirect_to @user  

else

  render 'edit'
end
end


private
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :aptno, :streetaddress, :city, :country, :stateprov, :poszip, :receive_newsletters, :terms_accepted,  :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar)
end

end
```

Comment: User.all will return a collection, so it would be more appropriately named @users. You are the trying to call an instance method on the collection. You need to iterate over the collection and call avatar on the single instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use a collection of users as a single user.

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  if params[:search]
    @users = User.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
  else
    @users = User.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end
end
```

---

```
<% if @users.any? %>
  <%= render @users %>
<% else %>
  <p>There are no posts containing the term(s) <%= params[:search] %>.</p>
<% end %>
```

Up to here the changes have only been to avoid developer confusion. However the real crux is your partial where you are using `@user` and not `user`.

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
```

The difference here is that `user` is a local variable which rails creates when rendering the partial. While `@user` is your miss-named collection!

So just use the local variable:

```
<%= image_tag user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
```

And pay attention to pluralization when naming your variables.

Comment: Also note that doing `<%= params[:search] %>` can leave your users open to  cross site scripting (XSS) attacks.  You need to escape it properly. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-scripting-xss

Comment: You rock! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this error because you're calling a method on an `Relation` object, not on a `User` object. Try calling .first on your relation object, it will return a `User` object. You can then call `.avatar` on that `User` object.

It looks like you are storing a relation into `@user` in your `index` method of `users_controller.rb`

```
def index
  @user = User.all
  if params[:search]
    @user = User.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
  else
    @user = User.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end
end
```

In both of these cases, you are calling `.all`, which will return a relation. You can use something along the llines of `User.where(criteria: <unique criteria>).first` to get an actual singular user object and save it to @user. **However**, as max pointed out, it doesn't make sense to have an index method that returns a singular user. So you should map this functionality to another controller method.

Comment: Ahh I see. Okay, sorry (so sorry...) for my newb-ness, but how would I implement that? E.g. how would I change my code to reflect that?

Comment: It still makes zero sense to have a index method that displays a single record. And she is obviously trying to display a collection. The naming is just off.

Comment: Agreed, and your answer provides a more robust solution than mine, and should be followed.

Comment: I put a note in my answer for you @max